# Python Subprocess CalledProcessError when calling remote shutdown command exit status 6

Tags: python, linux, ssh, subprocess, sshpass

My code runs a linux command to send a shutdown signal to a remote linux machine. Running the command on the linux terminal succeeds in shutting down the remote machine but using Python `subprocess` to call the command results in an error.

Code:

```
import subprocess
res = subprocess.check_call("sshpass -pPassword ssh root@192.168.1.2 sudo shutdown now", shell=True)
```

Result from Python 2.7:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'sshpass -pPassword ssh root@192.168.1.2 sudo shutdown now' returned non-zero exit status 6
```

Result from Python 3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 581, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'sshpass -pPassword ssh root@192.168.1.2 sudo shutdown now' returned non-zero exit status 6
```

With the target machine remaining unchanged.

Running `sshpass -pPassword ssh root@192.168.1.2 sudo shutdown now` alone on the command line succeeds and returns with `Connection to 192.168.1.2 closed.`

This seems like it could be a `subprocess` + `sshpass` issue.

What am I missing?

**Update**:
Haven't fixed the above problem but for some reason using `subprocess.check_output` instead of `check_call` executes the command successfully albeit returning `non-zero exit status 255`

Comment: Are you trying the script from the same host where you executed successfully the command directly from the command line?

Comment: Probably answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323730/sshpass-failing-with-exit-code-6)

Comment: @AlbertoRe All commands both on the terminal and from Python and being run on the exact same machine.

Comment: @user2722968 Target machine is already a known host to the host machine so does not solve this problem.

Comment: Well exit status 6 from sshpass [is](https://github.com/kevinburke/sshpass/blob/master/main.c) `RETURN_HOST_KEY_UNKNOWN` and according to the sourcecode [raised](https://github.com/kevinburke/sshpass/blob/master/main.c#L419) if there is no password prompt being detected. Your environment is probably not really the same, maybe a different user?

Comment: @user2722968 See my update above. Using `check_output` now returns a different exit status and succeeds the execution. If host key was unrecognised, would it not fail here also?

Comment: I'd rather suggest that instead of using `shell=True` and one big line, you should split the whole command into it's parts and use `shell=False` (the default). My guess is that sshpass fails to recognize the arguments.